# Exim4 as an Authenticated Smart Host

Tags: debian, exim, smarthost

I would like to set up Exim4 on Debian as an authenticated smart host, which behaves not terribly different from gmail (or google apps).

I want it to accept mail via TLS, require username and password credentials, and always rewrite the sender as the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to:

1.Setup a working Exim server

2.Setup authentication (eg cram_md5) (see section 35.1 of the manual)

> ```
> begin authenticators
> cram_md5_server:
>     driver = cram_md5
>     public_name = CRAM-MD5
>     server_secret = ${lookup{$1}lsearch{CONFDIR/crammd5.config}{$value}fail}
>     server_set_id = $1
> ```

3.Set the server to require tls (see section 38.1 of the manual)

> ```
> auth_over_tls_hosts = *
> ```

4.Configure sender rewriting (section 34.10 of the manual, examples from same)

> ```
> *@*.hitch.book.fict  $1@hitch.book.fict
> *@hitch.book.fict    ${lookup{$1}dbm{/etc/realnames}\
>                      {$value}fail}@hitch.book.fict bctfrF
> ```

There is a useful guide [here](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/exim/address_header.htm) to rewriting. Note that rewriting is *often* frowned upon as the reasons for rewriting are often nefarious.

You can test rewriting with `exim -brw <test_address>`.